How do I position a cylinder between two meshes in react-three-fiber?
I'm trying to build a small node diagram using react-three-fiber. It'll only have a few nodes and I would like to connect each node with a cylinder (the cylinders representing a link between nodes). You can see an example here:
import "./styles.css";
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";

export default function App() {
  const color = "rgb(255,0,0)";
  return (
    <div className="App" style={{ height: "600px" }}>
      <Canvas camera={{ position: [0, 0, 6.5] }}>
        <ambientLight intensity={0.75} />
        <directionalLight intensity={2.25} position={[1, 1, 5]} />
        <group>
          <mesh position={[1, 0, 2]}>
            <sphereGeometry args={[0.5, 32, 32]} />
            <meshStandardMaterial color={color} />
          </mesh>

          <mesh position={[-1, -1, 1]}>
            <sphereGeometry args={[0.5, 32, 32]} />
            <meshStandardMaterial color={color} />
          </mesh>

          <mesh position={[1, -1, 0]}>
            <sphereGeometry args={[0.5, 32, 32]} />
            <meshStandardMaterial color={color} />
          </mesh>

          <group position={[1, -1, 2]}>
            <mesh rotation={[Math.PI / 4 / 3, 0, (-Math.PI / 4 / 3) * 2]}>
              <cylinderGeometry args={[0.1, 0.1, 3, 32]} />
              <meshStandardMaterial color={color} />
            </mesh>
          </group>
        </group>
      </Canvas>
    </div>
  );
}

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/p7qkq2
However, I'm having a really hard time positioning a cylinder between two nodes. Given the position of two meshes, how would I figure out how to position a cylinder between them?

Don't just post a link to some other site. That can be useful, but ensure that you post all the relevant details (including code) in your question. See [ask]

Not directly answering your question, but LLMs like Claude can answer this type of question very quickly for free!

I've updated the question to include the code sample.

@AndyRay I thought you were spam at first but I'm in shock, that actually worked.  I'm honestly stunned at how good of an answer I got. Thank you so much for pointing me in that direction! I'll mark this question answered here with the example I got in a moment.

Here is an example of how to connect two meshes with a cylinder that modifies the original example I posted above:
import React, { useRef, useMemo } from "react";
import { Canvas, useFrame } from "@react-three/fiber";
import * as THREE from "three";

function positionCylinder(sphere1Ref, sphere2Ref, cylinderRef) {
  if (sphere1Ref.current && sphere2Ref.current && cylinderRef.current) {
    // Update cylinder position and rotation to connect the spheres
    const start = sphere1Ref.current.position;
    const end = sphere2Ref.current.position;

    const direction = end.clone().sub(start);
    const center = start.clone().add(direction.clone().multiplyScalar(0.5));

    cylinderRef.current.position.copy(center);
    cylinderRef.current.scale.set(0.5, direction.length() / 2, 0.5);
    cylinderRef.current.quaternion.setFromUnitVectors(
      new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0),
      direction.clone().normalize()
    );
  }
}

const SpheresAndCylinder = () => {
  const sphere1Ref = useRef();
  const sphere2Ref = useRef();
  const sphere3Ref = useRef();
  const cylinder1Ref = useRef();
  const cylinder2Ref = useRef();

  const sphere1Position = useMemo(() => new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 2), []);
  const sphere2Position = useMemo(() => new THREE.Vector3(-1, -1, 1), []);
  const sphere3Position = useMemo(() => new THREE.Vector3(1, -1, 0), []);

  useFrame(() => {
    positionCylinder(sphere1Ref, sphere2Ref, cylinder1Ref);
    positionCylinder(sphere2Ref, sphere3Ref, cylinder2Ref);
  });

  const color = "rgb(255,0,0)";

  return (
    <>
      <mesh ref={sphere1Ref} position={[1, 0, 2]}>
        <sphereGeometry args={[0.5, 32, 32]} position={sphere1Position} />
        <meshStandardMaterial color={color} />
      </mesh>

      <mesh ref={sphere2Ref} position={sphere2Position}>
        <sphereGeometry args={[0.5, 32, 32]} />
        <meshStandardMaterial color={color} />
      </mesh>

      <mesh ref={sphere3Ref} position={sphere3Position}>
        <sphereGeometry args={[0.5, 32, 32]} />
        <meshStandardMaterial color={color} />
      </mesh>

      <mesh ref={cylinder1Ref}>
        <cylinderGeometry args={[0.1, 0.1, 1, 32]} />
        <meshStandardMaterial color={color} />
      </mesh>

      <mesh ref={cylinder2Ref}>
        <cylinderGeometry args={[0.1, 0.1, 1, 32]} />
        <meshStandardMaterial color={color} />
      </mesh>
    </>
  );
};

const Scene = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{ height: "400px" }}>
      <Canvas camera={{ position: [0, 0, 6.5] }}>
        <ambientLight intensity={0.75} />
        <directionalLight intensity={2.25} position={[1, 1, 5]} />
        <SpheresAndCylinder />
      </Canvas>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Scene;

Working demo: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-three-fiber-nodes-forked-g6l6pn?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A13%2C1&workspaceId=fb2e9f6d-d82f-4b2a-b318-a5b500fd55f9
Special thanks to @AndyRay and his comment in my question which led me to the answer! Hope this can help anyone else that runs across this.
